# Where to find chess coaches?

Tags: coach

I tried my local chess club but they don't have any good recommendations. Could someone recommend a good website to find coaches?

It would be even better if it has sections to match local coaches as well.

Comment: Can't provide an answer specific to you, but at least some (U.S.) state chess associations provide listings of coaches for their state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Chess.com](http://www.chess.com/coaches) has a list of chess coaches, searchable by location, rating and other stuff.

In the [ICC](https://www.chessclub.com) store you can also hire chess coaches.

Answer (score 8):

https://lichess.org/coach also has a long list of coaches. I found my coach there and I'm happy with the result. We use Skype for audio and the Lichess study feature to share positions in real time, which is very convenient.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of sites with available chess coaches:

http://www.chess.com/coaches

http://www.chesstrainer.com (I actually trained with the coach here)

https://store.chessclub.com/teachers/

http://www.uschess.org/content/view/10002/131/

Comment: Hopefully you don't mind that I updated and made links from these suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

there is another very interesting in https://www.albertochueca.com and in addition he offers a very good chess guide...

Answer (score 1):

Depending which country you're in, your national chess federation or regional association may be able to give you contact details for coaches in your area.

If your local club doesn't, it might also be worth contacting other nearby clubs (if your club plays in a league, they should be able to give you contact details for the other clubs), as they may provide coaching or have members who give private tuition.